# How to merge two collections into one without any conditions

Tags: mongodb

I have two Different collections named X and Y i have to just send these two collections data into a new collection Z.
Is it possible to just send the two collections data into one.

I can see many similar questions but with many conditions in the data so here i don't need any conditions just clubbing the two collections of data into new collection.

Comment: what is MongoDB version ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, my Mongodb version is 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use copyTo command.

```
db.myt1.copyTo('myt3'); 
db.myt.copyTo('myt3');
```

Now we have myt3 as a copy of myt1 and myt collections.